# How to upgrade Python version used by Odoo 8 in Windows

Tags: python, odoo, upgrade

I have Odoo 8 on Windows with Python 2.7.6. I need to upgrade Python to 2.7.10.
I have Windows and Odoo 8 installs its own Python version.

Comment: I’m always curious to know; Why are you using Python 2?

Comment: That's the version that Odoo 8 for Windows installer uses. And I guess Odoo 8 doesn't work with Python 3.